# mysqldump doing a partial backup - incomplete table dump

Tags: mysql

I have a database of about 6GB in size and it has a table with 12.6 million rows. I tried to export the database into a SQL dump by:

mysqldump -u root -p db_name > db_name.sql

When the command finishes, the exported SQL dump file is just about 2GB and the primary table got exported only about 1 million rows.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 2GB filesize limit for some reason, the easiest way to get around this is using `split`:

```
mysqldump ... | split -b 250m - filename.sql-
```

You can also compress the files like this:

```
mysqldump ... | gzip -9c | split -b 250m - filename.sql.gz-
```

To restore from a non-compressed file, do this:

```
cat filename.sql-* | mysql ...
```

For a compressed file:

```
cat filename.sql-* | zcat | mysql ...
```

Of course if you want a single file, you can then `tar` the result.

Obviously you can replace the `250m` with a different size if you wish.

Comment: This is a great workaround in the meantime, but I highly suggest you dump your data to a location that will handle files of any size.  Otherwise, you are looking for headaches.  It should be as simple as reformatting with a filesystem that handles larger files.

Comment: the `...` in the commands is connecting to the database and selecting the table like you have in your original post.

Comment: i am not sure if reformatting the filesystem is always a very easy option.

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem probably is limited to 2gb files.

Comment: that may not compress it enough

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because some SQL Dump have limited size for dumping data.
you could not dump the database if it over the limit.

If you really want to do this you must compress the database.By using ZIP,GZIP,etc. Before dumping data.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar, though all the tables were exported up to a certain point.

I'd removed a column on which an old redundant View depended, and mysqldump quietly choked trying to 'export' the View